# sbt task dependency liquibase

Tags: sbt, liquibase

I'm using sbt for my project and using the liquibase plugin for database management. I want to configure a build-cycle so that the liquibase-update task is run before the integration test. I need some help on how to do this. So when running the it:test task, it must first run the liquibase-update task. I managed to run the liquibase-update task before running the test task using the following configuration:

(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn(liquibaseUpdate)

But I want it to be triggered before running the integration test. I tried the following configuration, but it does not work:

(test in IntegrationTest) <<= (test in IntegrationTest).dependsOn(liquibaseUpdate)

Comment: For me it works. Can you give us a minimal working example that shows your observed behaviour? Especially give us the sbt version.